# Failing to insert the foreign key in the owning table when save method is being fired from the non-owning object in a bidirectional relationship?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, bidirectional-relation

So I have Two entities 'Student' and 'Parents' and the relationship between them is of 'OneToOne'.

Owning side here is 'student'.

Student.java

```
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="pg-uuid",strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
    private UUID id;
    
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    private Parents parents;

        Student(){
    }
    
    Student(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    //Getters And Setters
```

Parents.java

```
import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name="parents")
public class Parents {
    
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator="pg-uuid",strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.type.PostgresUUIDType")
    private UUID id;
    
    @Column(name="father_name")
    private String fatherName;
    
    @Column(name="mother_name")
    private String motherName;
    
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "parents",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Student student;

        public Parents() {
    }

    public Parents(String fatherName,String motherName) {
        this.fatherName=fatherName;
        this.motherName = motherName;
    }
    //Getter and Setters
```

Database : POSTGRESQL

Student table

```
  Column   |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |      Default
-----------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------
 id        | uuid                  |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
 name      | character varying(50) |           |          |
 parent_id | uuid                  |           |          |
Indexes:
    "student_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "student_parent_id_key" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (parent_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "student_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parents(id)
```

Parents table

```
   Column    |         Type          | Collation | Nullable |      Default
-------------+-----------------------+-----------+----------+--------------------
 id          | uuid                  |           | not null | uuid_generate_v4()
 father_name | character varying(80) |           | not null |
 mother_name | character varying(80) |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "parents_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "student" CONSTRAINT "student_parent_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parents(id)
```

Note:-

1.) I'm using uuid_*generate*_v4() as default in both the tables for auto generating UUID

2.)parent_id in the student table is the foreign key that has reference for parents table primary key;

3.) Both the entities are in a bidirectional relationship.

My StudentApp.java

```
public class StudentApp {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SessionFactory factory=new Configuration()
                .configure()
                .addAnnotatedClass(Student.class)
                .addAnnotatedClass(Parents.class)
                .buildSessionFactory();
        
        Session session=factory.getCurrentSession();
        
        try {
            
            Student student=new Student("Sinchan Nohara");
            Parents parents=new Parents("Hiroshi Nohara","Missy Nohara");
            
                        student.setParents(parents);
 
            session.beginTransaction();
            
            session.save(student)
            
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            session.close();
            factory.close();
        }
                
    }
}
```

So if I run the code given below in my StudentApp.java

```
Student student=new Student("Sinchan Nohara");
Parents parents=new Parents("Hiroshi Nohara","Missy Nohara");
            
student.setParents(parents);
 
session.beginTransaction();
            
session.save(student)
            
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

its working fine .

Student table (Owning side)

```
                  id                  |      name      |              parent_id

--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------------------------------
89879cd1-a562-48f3-8632-9eaa5d288f5f | Sinchan Nohara | 82206833-b0d0-4e99-94f5-cab32he8a361
```

Parents Table (Referenced Side)

```
                  id                  |  father_name   | mother_name
--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------
 82206833-b0d0-4e99-94f5-cab32he8a361 | Hiroshi Nohara | Missy Nohara
```

But when I try to run the code given below in my StudentApp.java

```
Student student=new Student("Sinchan Nohara");
Parents parents=new Parents("Hiroshi Nohara","Missy Nohara");
            
parents.setStudent(student);
 
session.beginTransaction();
            
session.save(parents)
            
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

then the foreign key(parent_id) in the student table is not getting inserted.

look at the tables below now,

Parents table

```
                  id                  |  father_name   | mother_name
--------------------------------------+----------------+--------------
 380e4daa-0cba-4e26-aa3f-446dbc4fd2c0 | Hiroshi Nohara | Missy Nohara
```

Student Table

```
                  id                  |      name      | parent_id
--------------------------------------+----------------+-----------
 de062q8d-ff58-4c05-a342-7uu67a4c842d | Sinchan Nohara |
```

Why this is happening? and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with bidirectionnal relations with hibernate is tricky. In fact, your model shows that the relation is owned by the `student`. When you define the relation, it is not enough to set the `student` of a `parents` to make it work. You have to set the `parents` of the `student`.
This is tricky because when you load a `student` or a `parents` you will get both objects with their bidirectional relation properly set.
The problems arise when you do create, update or delete. That's where the owner of the relation becomes important.
By the way, in your case, I would rather set the `parents` as the owner of the relation to the `student` since, I imagine, `parents` may exist without `student` and not the opposite.

Comment: thanks it worked, I just needed to add this line " student.setParents(this); " in my setStudent-setter method in Parents.java class.

Comment: Indeed, it can be a way of doing it.